# Thymeleaf + Spring-Boot - why can't I access static resources?

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, static-resource

My project tree looks like this:

[image]

I can access the templates now, but can't load static resources such as CSS, images, and JS.

I have a `common.html` fragment where I declare all my static resources, for instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app.css}"/>
```

A header fragment where I include `common.html` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:include="fragments/common :: commonFragment" lang="en"></head>
// page body
</html>
```

A `default.html` file for layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head th:include="fragments/common :: commonFragment" lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
    <title>Touch</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-dataType" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{/static/images/favicon.ico}"  type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
<div th:id="defaultFragment" th:fragment="defaultFragment" class="container">
    <div id="header" th:replace="fragments/header :: headerFragment" />
        <div layout:fragment="content" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, on my `application.properties` file, I have these entries:

```
#SPRING RESOURCE HANDLING
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/

#THYMELEAF
spring.thymeleaf.cache = true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template = true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location = true
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=1
```

But I keep getting the same `No mapping found` message.

```
32190 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/central/css/app.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem with the following code:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:templates/
```

Comment: Holly sh.. I was looking for this so much, I was getting a blank page and I tough I was doing somethign wrong, but the problem was the static content, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2 and not getting any of my static content. I discovered two solutions that worked for me:

---

**Option #1 - Stop using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation**

This annotation disables some automatic configuration, including the part that automatically serves static content from commonly-used locations like `/src/main/resources/static`. If you don't really need `@EnableWebMvc`, then just remove it from your `@Configuration` class.

---

**Option #2 - Implement `WebMvcConfigurer` in your `@EnableWebMvc` annotated class and implement**`addResourceHandlers()`

Do something like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringMVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/vendor/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/vendor/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

}
```

Just remember that your code is now in charge of managing all static resource paths.

---

Answer (score 3):

Use the **spring.resources.static-locations** in your properties to define the static resources locations (making them directly publicly available):

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/your/static/resources/here/like/central/css/
```

you can provide comma separated values i.e. [taken from the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties):

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/ # Locations of static resources.
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but it did not work. I am using a very default project structure Spring Boot should really have an issue with this...

Comment: what is the error you are getting if adding the above property?

Comment: I added spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/static/css/,classpath:/resources/static/images/,classpath:/resources/static/js/`` to `application.properties` and got
`51669 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/central/css/app.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' `

Comment: if you permissioned "/resources/stati‌​c/css/" then why do you expect /central/css/.. to work? There is an unpermissioned central directory along the way

Comment: I expected `th:href="@{/css/app.css}"` to be accessed after `classpath:/resources/static/`. I have tried the following just now `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/,classpath:/resources/static/,classpath:/resources/static/css/` and I still get the same no mapping found error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add mapping of your static resources in link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/app.css}"
href="../../../css/app.css" />
```

Comment: adding the static mapping `href="../../../css/app.css"` kind of defeats the whole point of letting Spring Boot handling this, right?